# Combining two arrays with OR like operator

Tags: ruby

What's the best way to combine two arrays `a1` and `a2`

```
a1 = [nil, 1, nil, 1, 1, 2]
a2 = [nil, nil, 2, 2, 1, 2]
```

So the result of combining would be

```
[nil, 1, 2, nil, 1, 2]
```

Is there any way to do this without `if` statement ?

Rules are:

1. If one of `a1[n]`, `a2[n]` is `nil` then result is `a1[n] || a2[n]`
2. If both are `not nil` then:

   - `a1[n] == a2[n]` result is `a1[n]`
   - `a1[n] != a2[n]` result is `nil`

Comment: maybe result should be `[nil, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2]`?

Comment: So what would happen if say the value in the first array is 1 and the second array is 2. Which value do you want to keep? or should they be summed?

Comment: Can you explain the result?

Comment: Ok, I'm editing it now.

Comment: no way to do it without if, because it isn't a standard logic.

Comment: @Ilya: the question doesn't say "without `if`", it says "without `if` statements". That's trivial: Ruby doesn't *have* `if` statements, it only has `if` expressions! In fact, Ruby doesn't have statements *at all*, literally *everything* is an expression. Therefore, *all* Ruby code is by definition "without `if` statement".

Comment: @JörgWMittag, could you expand a little more on *"Ruby doesn't have statements at all, literally everything is an expression"*? Are statements not expressions?

Comment: @ndn: a statement is in some sense the *opposite* of an expression. An expression evaluates to a result value (any may, in an impure language, also have an optional side-effect). A statement *has no value*, and thus *must* have a side-effect (otherwise it doesn't do anything at all). In Ruby, you can choose not to do anything with the value of an expression, but it still has a value, and thus still is an expression. There are some things that are referred to as "statements" in the YARV source code (and which leak through into error messages, RDocs, or the ISO Ruby Language Specification), …

Comment: … but they aren't technically statements. They are expressions that always evaluate to `nil`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, isn't Ruby's `return` a *"real"* statement then? It has the side effect of forcing the method to return a value, but it does not evaluate to anything itself.

Comment: @ndn according to `ruby -e 'a = return'`, it's a "void value expression"

Comment: Or they are expressions whose value cannot be observed. (E.g. `next`, `break`, `return`.)

Comment: @JörgWMittag, wait, so how do you differentiate between an *"expression who's value cannot be observed with side effects"* and a statement?

Comment: @JörgWMittag, or between something *"with no value"* and something *"who's value cannot be observed"*?

Comment: @ndn: a statement has no value. An expression has a value. However, the `return` expression for example immediately changes the execution context back to the caller, so while it *does* have a value (and thus is an expression), that value cannot be observed. Ruby will sometimes detect this through clever use of syntax rules (e.g. `return` is not syntactically valid in an assignment or in an argument list) and generate a warning or even raise an exception, but still, it is an expression. It returns a value. You just can't do anything useful with that value.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, but how do you know that it has a value if you can't observe it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a1.zip(a2).map { |x, y| [x || y] == [x, y].uniq.compact ? (x || y) : nil }
```

Comment: without if statement, see the question)

Comment: @Ilya, this is not an if statement. xd But you can simulate if statements without the actual tools in the language. Is this just an exercise not to use them? Does using methods that use if statements internally count?

Comment: its just a question requirement

Comment: @Ilya, I think the question was more in the lines *"yes, I can use 5 conditionals, but it doesn't look elegant, is there a more dense solution"* as opposed to *"don't use conditionals"*. If OP confirms it was the latter, I will try to edit my current solution.

Comment: Yep, the point was to make it more elegant, withouth hard coding all these rules with if statements.

Answer (score 0):

I believe my answer addresses the question as it is expressed by both the stated requirements and the title ("...with OR-like operator").

```
a1 = [nil, 1, nil, 1, 1, 2]
a2 = [nil, nil, 2, 2, 1, 2]

[a1, a2].transpose.map {|x1,x2| (x1.nil? || x2.nil? || (x1==x2) || nil) && (x1 || x2)}
  #=> [nil, 1, 2, nil, 1, 2]
```

When

```
x1 = 1
x2 = 2
```

we compute

```
(x1.nil? || x2.nil? || (x1==x2) || nil) && (x1 || x2)
  #=> (false || false || false || nil) && (x1 || x2)
  #=> nil && (x1 || x2)
  #=> nil
```

In all other cases we obtain

```
true && (x1 || x2)
  #=> x1 || x2
```

so

```
nil || nil #=> nil
1 || nil   #=> 1
nil || 2   #=> 2
1 || 1     #=> 1
2 || 2     #=> 2
```